# Allow non-admin, local user account, to shutdown Windows Server remotely

Tags: windows, remote, shutdown

For security purposes, on server1, I created local user account, shutdowntest, and gave it local security policy permission "Force shutdown from a remote system".

Now I want to shutdown server1 remotely, from another server, with sysinternals psshutdown.exe

```
psshutdown \\server1 -u server1\shutdowntest -p pAsSw0rD -f /t 0
```

I get output:

```
PsShutdown v2.6 - Shutdown, logoff and power manage local and remote systems
Copyright (C) 1999-2023 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Couldn't access server1:
Access is denied.

If server1 is already performing a shutdown operation you must
abort it before issuing a different command.
```

Does server1\shutdowntest local user need additional rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to run the shutdown successfully, you have to get over another issue: The remote UAC restricts the user rights if logged on from remote. This blocks your shutdown execution.

do you try this solution:

> regedit as administator on PC to be shutdown
>
> HLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System New
>
> DWORD(32) / edit existing name:- LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy set
>
> value to:- 1

Quoted from: https://smallworldsolutions.co.uk/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=10

Best Regards

Comment: With sysinternals psshutdown,  setting LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy to 1 did help, however, local user has to be in the Administrators group. However, using the default "shutdown" command, doesnt require registry editing, nor administrator rights. Thanks